# Moving a comet in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

[image: Added a picture]

I want a commet in pygame to shoot across the screen. Here is my commet class

```
class Commet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x  = -10
        self.y = 10
        self.radius = 20
        self.commet = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\A level python codes\final game\commet.png")
        self.commet = pygame.transform.scale(self.commet, (self.radius, self.radius))
        self.drop = 0.0000009
        self.speed = 2
        self.pos = 0
        self.commets = []
```

Then i added 20 commets  to the `self.commets` list.

```
  def tail(self, n): # n is a variable used to denote the length of the self.commets
        for i in range(n):
            if len(self.commets) <= n - 1:
                self.commets.append(Commet())
```

I am having two problems. The first problem being moving the commet. To move it i did this

```
def move_tail(self):
    for c in  self.commets:
        c.x += self.speed
    for i in range(len(self.commets) - 1):
         self.commets[i].y += ((self.commets[i + 1].x) ** 2) * self.drop
```

For x- coordinate i just added 2 to its value every frame. However, for the `y`value of the commet, i want it to produce a tail-like following effect. I tried assigning the `y` value of the commet to the square of `x` value of the commet in the index position one above the commet we are referring to in the list `self.commets`.I expected the commets to follow each other  along a general x = y **2 quadradic curve. They do follow the curve but all at the same rate(i expected them to follow at different rate because all the commets have different x values), which dosent give me the tail-like effect. How would i be able to produce this tail-like effect?

The second part of my question is that i want the commets following the first one get smaller and smaller. I tried decreasing the `radius` value, which is used to scale the image i imported. The code looks like this

```
    # Decrease radius
    for i in range(n):
        self.commets[i].radius = i + 1
```

When i print out the values of radius of the commets on the console, they range from 1 to 20, as i expect them to, but the size of the image that  appears on the screen is the same for all the commets in the list.The following code is how i blit the commet

```
  for i in range(n):
        self.commets[i].pos = i * 10 #  This line maintains a certain x- distance between commets

    for c in self.tails:
        D.blit(c.commet, (c.x - c.pos, c.y))

        if self.pos >= n:
            self.pos = n
```

Comment: As the comet moves, it's going to need to create a new images of itself and update any previous copies of itself—think of a snake like a Python. `;¬)` To do this, you'll need to store the currently active image is a container, like a `list` (up to some maximum number of them).

Comment: @Thomas Weller I added a image. I basically just want some smaller circles following the bigger circles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you want your comet to fly from left to right on a FullHD screen.

The comet shall start at the left side at a y coordinate of 900, then reach its highest point at x=1400 and y = 100 and then fall to 600 at the right side of the screen.

[image: Comet flight]

A parabola is generally y = ax²+bx+c.

To be independent of the screen resolution, you would of course calculate those values from some percentage, say 900 ~ screen height * 83%, 600 ~ screen height * 55%, 1400 ~ screen width * 73%, 100 ~ screen height * 9%

With three points given, you can calculate a parabola:

```
class ParabolaFrom3Points:
    def __init__(self, points: list):
        self.a = (points[0][0] * (points[1][1] - points[2][1]) + points[1][0] * (
                points[2][1] - points[0][1]) + points[2][0] * (points[0][1] - points[1][1])) / (
                         (points[0][0] - points[1][0]) * (points[0][0] - points[2][0]) * (
                         points[2][0] - points[1][0]))
        self.b = (points[0][0] ** 2 * (points[1][1] - points[2][1]) + points[1][0] ** 2 * (
                points[2][1] - points[0][1]) + points[2][0] ** 2 * (points[0][1] - points[1][1])) / (
                         (points[0][0] - points[1][0]) * (points[0][0] - points[2][0]) * (
                         points[1][0] - points[2][0]))
        self.c = (points[0][0] ** 2 * (points[1][0] * points[2][1] - points[2][0] * points[1][1]) +
                  points[0][0] * (points[2][0] ** 2 * points[1][1] - points[1][0] ** 2 * points[2][1]) +
                  points[1][0] * points[2][0] * points[0][1] * (points[1][0] - points[2][0])) / (
                         (points[0][0] - points[1][0]) * (points[0][0] - points[2][0]) * (
                         points[1][0] - points[2][0]))

    def y(self, x: int) -> int:
        return int(self.a * x ** 2 + self.b * x + self.c)
```

The Comet is quite simple then. It just needs to know its parabola function and can then calculate the y from the x.

```
class Comet:
    def __init__(self, radius: int, para: ParabolaFrom3Points):
        self.x = -radius  # Be invisible at the beginning
        self.radius = radius
        self.para = para

    def move(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def paint(self, screen):
        x = self.x
        radius = self.radius
        for tail in range(20):
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255, 255, 255], (int(x), self.para.y(x)), radius)
            x = x - radius / 2
            radius -= 1
```

Test code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.fastevent.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))

pygame.display.set_caption('Comet example')
comet = Comet(20, ParabolaFrom3Points([(0, 1080 * 0.83), (1920 * 0.73, 1080 * 0.12), (1920, 1080 * 0.55)]))
for x in range(-20, 1920 + 200, 3):
    comet.move(x)
    comet.paint(window)
    clock.tick(90)
    pygame.display.flip()
    window.fill([0, 0, 0])

pygame.quit()
```